# How to set Google Site's page authority?

Tags: google-sites

I have developed a Google Site application, there are some pages in this Google Site application. Some pages user A has authority to read, user B doesn't have. And some pages user B has authority to read, A doesn't have. How could I set the authority on Google Site's page?

Thanks!﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under share, enable page level permissions

Comment: need to check if this works for sites created under a google app domain

Comment: Yes, the button to enable this is at the top right of the page hardly noticed it over there! Very handy to know thanks @Shelley